# Element type is invalid expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `App`.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  HashRouter,
  Route,
  Switch,
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./scss/style.scss";

import Routes from "./routes";

const loading = (
  <div className="pt-3 text-center">
    <div className="sk-spinner sk-spinner-pulse"></div>
  </div>
);

function App() {
  // Containers
  const TheLayout = React.lazy(() => import("./containers/TheLayout"));

  // Pages

  // const Register = React.lazy(() => import('./views/pages/register/Register'));
  // const Page404 = React.lazy(() => import('./views/pages/page404/Page404'));
  // const Page500 = React.lazy(() => import('./views/pages/page500/Page500'));
  // const Pistatus = React.lazy(()=> import('./views/theme/pistatus/pistatus'));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <main>
        <Routes />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What does the `Routes` component look like?

Comment: it contains lazy loading as well as path for every component

Comment: Yes but can you add to your question. I can't see any issue with your App component, so issue might be in your Routes component

Comment: Instead of pasting unformatted code in a comment, please edit the original with the information in a code block.

Comment: Ok so in future add the code to your question, not as a comment. And yes Routes is the issue, it's not a component at all, it's an array of objects. You can't render objects. You should be rendering a `Route` component _per_ object in the array, e.g. instead of `<Routes />` you should render `{routes.map(route => <Route key={route.path} {...route} />)}` - and also, your Home object is missing a `component` property

Comment: This guy is geneous ;)

Comment: why @pramodsingh

Comment: why did you comment "import React from 'react';" above?
btw your router expecting Component name, but you are providing rendered component to it. @Perumal